# Primefaces show confirmation box if some rows are selected from datagrid

Tags: primefaces, dialog, confirmation

Using primefaces 5. We are having a datagrid with checkboxes and delete button. When the user selects some rows from datagrid and clicks on delete button then a confirmation dialog box is displayed which asks the user to press yes or no. 
We want to display an alert message if no row is selected from the datagrid and delete button is clicked and confirmation dialog box should also not be shown. If user selects row from datagrid and clicks on delete then confirmation box should be displayed.

We are using global confirmation box. My code for delete button is as given below

Kindly, let me know how can this be achieved

Comment: <p:commandButton id="delete"  action="#{myBean.deleteTrafficRow}"  icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" title="DeleteButton"  onclick="setSelectedRowId('rowId',#{myBean.id})" update=":myForm">
<f:param name="diffPage" value="isNewPage"/>  
 <p:confirm header="Delete Record"   message="Are you sure about deleting this record?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true">
<p:commandButton title="Yes" value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/> <p:commandButton title="No"  value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"/></p:confirmDialog>